# Select item of array of objects from deep property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have this array:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "name": "item 1",
        "id": 123
    },{
        "name": "item 2",
        "id": 456
    }
];
```

What would be the proper way to get an item based on the `id` property? With this example, say I know I want the `item` for which `item.id == 456`.

**I don't want jquery answers.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var item = myArray.filter(function(item) { return item.id === 456; })[0];
```

Comment: I'm gonna validate this as it actually is the appropriate solution. But here's a jsperf that shows this isn't the fastest: http://jsperf.com/array-filter-performance/4

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a search function like below:

```
function searchArray(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if(myArray[i].id == id) {
        return myArray[i];
      }
    }
    console.log(id + ' not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++ ) {
    if ( myArray[index].id == 456 )
       //Item found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 for (var i in myArray) {
      if(myArray[i].id == 456) {
            return myArray[i];
          }
    }
```